# Windows 10 Disable Animations via regedit/script

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, default-settings

Is there a way to turn off the "Play animations in Windows" setting via command line (batch/vbs/reg commands, etc.)?  Normally, you have to navigate to **PC Settings > Ease of Access > Other Options** and the setting is at the top, under **Visual options**; you have to slide the setting to Off.

I need to implement the disabling of this feature in a script.  I have already tried setting the **VisualFxSetting** registry parameter to 2 (see [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20516428/how-could-i-disable-windows-effects-through-batch) thread)
and it seems to turn off all the other stuff, but not this one setting.  You can test whether or not it is enabled by maximizing/minimizing a window.

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how to change the toggle, but this will turn the animations off. Restart or re-login after running as Admin.

```
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics" /v MinAnimate /t REG_SZ /d 0 /f >nul 2>&1
```

Comment: that did it - exactly what I was after.  THANKS!  Yeah, it didn't change the PC Settings toggle button (which might confuse a user), but I don't care - does what I want.

Comment: This works for Windows 11 also.