# Can I disable Windows 10 animations with a batch file?

Tags: windows-10, visual-effects

I'd like to disable animations in Windows 10, specifically animations for maximizing/minimizing windows. It doesn't look like each key has its own registry setting, and I don't see it in this list of values: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957204.aspx

Is this possible, or is this something I would have to do manually?

It would be nice if I could disable animations in general, but I'd be happy if I could even just write a script that would disable only the maximize/minimize animations:

[image]

Running [this solution](https://superuser.com/questions/1052763/windows-10-disable-animations-via-regedit-script) does not work:

```
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics" /v MinAnimate /t REG_SZ /d 0 /f >nul 2>&1
```

[This option requires a logout/login or restart](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/127261-animate-windows-when-minimizing-maximizing.html), unlike the manual method which takes effect immediately (preferred).

Comment: Then you have to manually calculate the `UsePreferenceMask` registry and put the value in reg add command. For window animation the bit place is 1 and value 0 disables it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use PowerShell! We need to invoke [`SystemParametersInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947(v=vs.85).aspx) with an appropriately configured [`ANIMATIONINFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724197(v=vs.85).aspx) structure, since that Windows API function sends the window message that causes the change to take effect immediately. I wrote this script:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] public struct ANIMATIONINFO {
        public uint cbSize;
        public bool iMinAnimate;
    }
    public class PInvoke { 
        [DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool SystemParametersInfoW(uint uiAction, uint uiParam, ref ANIMATIONINFO pvParam, uint fWinIni);
    }
"@
$animInfo = New-Object ANIMATIONINFO
$animInfo.cbSize = 8
$animInfo.iMinAnimate = $args[0]
[PInvoke]::SystemParametersInfoW(0x49, 0, [ref]$animInfo, 3)
```

The C# part defines the structure and function that we need to call. Then the script creates the animation configuration structure, and finally it calls the function. `0x49` is the code that tells `SystemParametersInfo` to set the animation setting and the `3` in the last parameter specifies that we want both the user profile to be updated and the setting change notification sent.

To use the script, save it as a `.ps1` file, e.g. `windowanim.ps1`. Follow the instructions in the Enabling Scripts section of [the PowerShell tag wiki](https://superuser.com/tags/powershell/info) to allow script execution, then you can run this command from a batch file to disable window animations:

```
powershell -c .\windowanim.ps1 $false
```

If you want to enable the animations, supply `$true` to the script instead.

If the function invocation is successful, you'll see `True` printed to the console, no matter whether you enabled or disabled animations.

Comment: Will this all work without admin rights?

Comment: @InterLinked Yes, I believe it does.

Comment: This is great - works like a charm and very quick! I'm a fan of PowerShell myself but usually rely on batch files for things like this. I guess there are some things batch can't do!